# spark cannot find java directory properly

Tags: java, apache-spark

I built a cluster in Ubuntu 20.04 and spark 3.0.0

After that, I spark-submit and I get the following error.

```
Exception from cluster was: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/adoptopenjdk-8.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java" (in directory "/home/ubuntu/spark-3.0.0-bin-hadoop2.7/work/driver-20201207053401-0000"): error=2, No such file or directory
java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/adoptopenjdk-8.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java" (in directory "/home/ubuntu/spark-3.0.0-bin-hadoop2.7/work/driver-20201207053401-0000"): error=2, No such file or directory
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1128)
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1071)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.worker.ProcessBuilderLike$$anon$3.start(DriverRunner.scala:264)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.worker.DriverRunner.runCommandWithRetry(DriverRunner.scala:229)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.worker.DriverRunner.runDriver(DriverRunner.scala:210)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.worker.DriverRunner.prepareAndRunDriver(DriverRunner.scala:193)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.worker.DriverRunner$$anon$2.run(DriverRunner.scala:96)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: error=2, No such file or directory
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.forkAndExec(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.<init>(ProcessImpl.java:340)
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(ProcessImpl.java:271)
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1107)
    ... 6 more
20/12/07 14:34:06 INFO ShutdownHookManager: Shutdown hook called
```

I set $JAVA_HOME and register export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64 in ./conf/spark-env.sh

but still try to find macOS Java dir.

/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64 is correct dir.

i submit app from mac to ubuntu in EC2

this is submitting command

```
./bin/spark-submit --master spark://15.xxx.42.xx:7077 \
--deploy-mode cluster \
--class com.mysterico.TfIdf \
--driver-memory 2G \
--executor-memory 2G \
--driver-cores 1 \
--executor-cores 2 \
--num-executors 2 \
/home/ubuntu/food-analytics-assembly-0.1.jar
```

Please help.

Comment: /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines is generally where macOS installs java. Also, homebrew would set JAVA_HOME for you... But what's this about ubuntu? Seems like you've got conflicting file paths in here because the Ubuntu machine is throwing the error because /Library (a macOS filesystem path) can't be found

Comment: JAVA in Ubuntu is /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64 

but driver try to find incorrect path 

that's problem

Comment: Sure, so you're submitting the code how? The driver is running remotely?

Comment: yes.  i submit app from mac to ubuntu

i upload command just now please check

Comment: Still confused. If you're submitting from the Mac, then you wouldn't have a file path `/home/ubuntu` on the Mac...

Comment: i tried before 
but it occur java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: /Users/ian/workspace/spark/food-analytics/target/scala-2.12/food-analytics-assembly-0.1.jar


./bin/spark-submit --master spark://15.xxx.42.xx:7077 \
--deploy-mode cluster \
--class com.mysterico.TfIdf \
--driver-memory 2G \
--executor-memory 2G \
--driver-cores 1 \
--executor-cores 2 \
--num-executors 2 \
/Users/ian/workspace/spark/food-analytics/target/scala-2.12/food-analytics-assembly-0.1.jar


so i send jar file to cluster

Comment: Seems to me that you're ssh'd into the EC2 machine and running the submit command

Comment: yes it can but it still to problem

i try to submit in ubuntu instance but it shutdown with no error

so i try remotely

Comment: 1) Errors wouldn't be shown since your driver is in the cluster. You'd have to look at the Spark History Server for that 2) I think that option would work best here since something is trying to send over properties of your Mac filesystem

Comment: @ian were you able to resolve the issue? I'm facing a similar [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73655323/spark-submit-sends-wrong-java-path-to-driver)